# Should I create Images folder in netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I am developing a java application in netbeans, to save image icons,  should i create a new images folder or there is already an images folder created?

I have created an image folder in the project, to set an image icon to JFrame,

```
URL iconURL = this.getClass().getResource("images/images.jpg");

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
    frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

error

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Comment: if its in your project then it should be `"images/images.jpg"`

Comment: after changing it to images/images.jpg, still recieving the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether you have a directory created, I suspect this

```
getResource("images\\images.jpg");
```

is a problem and you should specify the resource path as `images/images.jpg` (i.e. a forward slash, regardless of the platform. The slash is a resource separator and not necessarily referring to the filesystem)

I wouldn't expect NetBeans to do anything for you without an explicit request, and as such you should create whatever folders/resources you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one of the problem Netbeans has, once you have insert the image to your GUI it will always try to look for the image from the first location you had the image in. I would suggest to create an image package to keep it clean and try not to move the images from the package.

to solve the issue you have right now you can insert the image back to the previous stage I believe you had your image in the same package as your classes.

Or try this method

```
setIcon();
```

You can create the `setIcon`  just like below

```
public void setIcon() {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("images/images.jpg")));
        }
    }
```